# How to get Flutter container to start at the left edge of the screen?

Tags: flutter

I would like my container to start from the left edge, so that you only see three sides of the container: the top, bottom, and right. I've tried making the margins (0, x, y, z) from LTRB, but the container is still floating out farther right than I'd like. [image: must shift mentions left]

My code:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 170, 0),
            child: Text('MENTIONS', 
...
```

Comment: It works fine for me, but try adding `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` to the `Column`.

Comment: That works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // <=== try this maybe
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
            ),
            
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 170, 0),
            child: Text('MENTIONS',
```